# Displaying all pages in dropdown

Tags: php, wordpress, select

I am new to wordpress, i want to display all pages in a select box with value of their id. I know get_pages() is the function get all pages, but dont know about listing with their id anyone can help?

Comment: this question suits here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I guess you should use `wp_dropdown_pages()` , for more information you can google that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form action="">
<select>

<?php // Query for listing all pages in the select box loop
$my_wp_query = new WP_Query();
$all_wp_pages = $my_wp_query->query( array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
));

foreach ($all_wp_pages as $value){
    $post = get_page($value);
    $title = $post->post_title;
    $id = $post->ID;

    // For example
    // <option value="pageId32">Page title</option>

    echo '<option value="pageId' . $id. '">' . $title . '</option>';

}; ?>

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`wp_dropdown_pages`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_pages) function

From the documentation

> Displays a list of pages in a select (i.e dropdown) box with no submit
>   button.