# Wordpress php list all pages alphabetically

Tags: php, wordpress, dropdown

I found this code on here that pulls all wordpress pages and displays them in a dropdown list. My question is what needs to be changed to have these pages listed alphabetically?

```
<form action="">
<select>

<?php // Query for listing all pages in the select box loop
$my_wp_query = new WP_Query();
$all_wp_pages = $my_wp_query->query( array(
'post_type' => 'page',
'posts_per_page' => -1
));

foreach ($all_wp_pages as $value){
$post = get_page($value);
$title = $post->post_title;
$id = $post->ID;

// For example
// <option value="pageId32">Page title</option>

echo '<option value="pageId' . $id. '">' . $title . '</option>';

}; ?>

</select>
```

URL of above code: [Displaying all pages in dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284107/displaying-all-pages-in-dropdown)

Thanks in Advance! :)
Tracy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add parameters

`'orderby' => 'title',
 'order'   => 'ASC', // or DESC`
Please find updated code.
.

```
<?php // Query for listing all pages in the select box loop
$my_wp_query = new WP_Query();
$all_wp_pages = $my_wp_query->query( array(
'post_type' => 'page',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
 'orderby' => 'title',
 'order'   => 'ASC', // or DESC
));

foreach ($all_wp_pages as $value){
$post = get_page($value);
$title = $post->post_title;
$id = $post->ID;

// For example
// <option value="pageId32">Page title</option>

echo '<option value="pageId' . $id. '">' . $title . '</option>';

}; ?>

</select>
```

Comment: Use get_posts()  instead of WP_Query since get_posts() does not changes any global variables and more safe to use.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add sorting in WP_Query

```
 $all_wp_pages = $my_wp_query->query( array(
      'post_type' => 'page',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'orderby' => 'title',
 ));
```

Answer (score 0):

add `orderby` and `order` to query array:

```
$all_wp_pages = $my_wp_query->query( array(
      'post_type' => 'page',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'orderby' => 'title',
      'order'   => 'ASC', // or DESC
 ));
```